# Difference between condition and state

Tags: word-usage

> My ill uncle’s general state in medical report of  was seeming  bad.
>
> My uncle’s general conditon in medical report  was seeming bad.

In these sentences , are there any difference between two sentences in meaning because of two different words?

Answer (score 2):

**In the case** you mentioned, ***either*** can be used because [*state* means *condition*](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/state_1?q=state) of someone/body.

However, be cautious! It is not always interchangeable.

> How's your <del>condition</del> state of mind? 
>  For a patient in hospital - How's his <del>state</del> condition? 
>  He developed a very serious <del>state</del> condition called *neuroendocrine tumors.* He's in a very bad *state.*